# How can I plot the duration of a program in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I'm trying to plot the duration of some programs that is running in the night, I export the program duration data into a CSV file so that later on can be analyzed. (something like this)

[image: example]

Here are my code and CSV examples:

CSV:

```
 na,programName,totaal,na,startDate,endDate,Date
 ?,"to/check.apl",54006,?,2017-02-27T20:04:07.233,2017-02- 27T20:05:01.239,2017-02-27T00:00:00.000
 ?,"to/ibx.apl",143887,?,2017-02-27T20:07:55.627,2017-02-27T20:10:19.514,2017-02-27T00:00:00.000
 ?,"to/checker.apl",2039600,?,2017-02-27T20:14:37.662,2017-02-27T20:48:37.262,2017-02-27T00:00:00.000
```

python code:

```
 import matplotlib
 from pandas import *
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy  as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

 data = "miFile.csv"
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(data)
 df = df.set_index('totaal')

 newDf = df[['programName','startDate','endDate']]
```

So far I get datetime error so I tried to fix this by doing this(also no luck to plot):

```
 newDf['startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(newDf['startDate'])
 newDf['endDate'] = pd.to_datetime(newDf['endDate'])

 #pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["2017-02-27T20:04:07.233"]) format= "%d, %m, %y, %H: %M: %S")

 newDf.plot('programName','startDate','endDate')

 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for creating `df`, then get difference of columns and [convert timedelta](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion) to `minutes` for [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
temp=u"""na,programName,totaal,na,startDate,endDate,Date
?,"to/check.apl",54006,?,2017-02-27T20:04:07.233,2017-02-27T20:05:01.239,2017-02-27T00:00:00.000
?,"to/ibx.apl",143887,?,2017-02-27T20:07:55.627,2017-02-27T20:10:19.514,2017-02-27T00:00:00.000
?,"to/checker.apl",2039600,?,2017-02-27T20:14:37.662,2017-02-27T20:48:37.262,2017-02-27T00:00:00.000"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), index_col=[2], parse_dates=[4,5,6])

print (df.dtypes)
na                     object
programName            object
na.1                   object
startDate      datetime64[ns]
endDate        datetime64[ns]
Date           datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

```
df['duration'] = (df['endDate'] - df['startDate']).astype('timedelta64[m]')
newDf = df[['programName','duration']]
print (newDf)
            programName  duration
totaal                           
54006      to/check.apl       0.0
143887       to/ibx.apl       2.0
2039600  to/checker.apl      33.0

newDf.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine, I used  `newDf.plot('programName','duration')`  to get it right and I also used  `astype('timedelta64[s]')` to get it in seconds. But  I only see 7 program names which it should be like 70.

Comment: If test `print (df)` there is only 7 rows?

Comment: `print(df)` gives me this: `[70 rows x 6 columns]`

Comment: unfortunately it is confidential and i can't share, sorry.

Comment: problem still exists, but I think it has something todo with the lines(ticks) in the plot.

Comment: ok, is possible anonymize data? becasue I have no idea what is problem withut your real data. :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the pandas.read_csv() instead of the pandas.DataFrame.from_csv().
Then I'd consider the T that separates the days from the hours.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jezreal this is how my final solution looks like and it works fine. I plot in seconds because programs under 1 minute will be ignored, that won't be accurate in my case.

```
import matplotlib
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

data = "miFile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(data,index_col=[2], parse_dates=[4,5,6])

df['duration'] = (df['endDate'] - df['startDate']).astype('timedelta64[s]')
newDf = df[['programName','duration']]

newDf.plot('programName','duration')
plt.show()
```